# Deep learning model weights initialization problem

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, initialization

I am trying to create a model in TensorFlow. However the weights initialization seems to be wrong but I cannot understand why. So, my model has a hidden layer with sigmoid as activation function and the output layer uses softmax. I also use Xavier. So, To initialize the weights I use:

```
hidden_layer = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_size, hid_size], stddev=0.01)) * np.sqrt(1./input_size)

output_layer = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hid_size, output_size], stddev=0.01)) * np.sqrt(1./hid_size)
```

The standard deviation is given.

Do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Xavier you should consider using Xavier initializer, see  [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer) for the docs.

```
hidden_layer  = tf.get_variable("w1", shape=[input_size, hid_size], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

output_layer = tf.get_variable("w2", shape=[hid_size, output_size], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```